# Npm is not installing all dependencies of devDependencies in NestJS starter project

Tags: node.js, npm, nestjs

I'm trying to run `npm run build` in a nest project, but, I wanna run build with only devDependencies of starter project.

Steps to reproduce:

`git clone git@github.com:ndeitch/only-dev-deps.git`

`npm install --only=dev`

`npm run build`

Then, it gives an error: `Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'`

I ran `npm ls inherits` which prints the follow:

```
only-dev-deps@0.0.1 /Users/ndeitch/Desktop/nesttest/only-dev-deps
├─┬ @nestjs/cli@7.4.1
│ └─┬ webpack@4.43.0
│   ├─┬ memory-fs@0.4.1
│   │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   ├─┬ node-libs-browser@2.2.1
│   │ ├─┬ assert@1.5.0
│   │ │ └─┬ util@0.10.3
│   │ │   └── inherits@2.0.1 
│   │ ├─┬ crypto-browserify@3.12.0
│   │ │ ├─┬ browserify-cipher@1.0.1
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ browserify-aes@1.2.0
│   │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ browserify-des@1.0.2
│   │ │ │   ├─┬ des.js@1.0.1
│   │ │ │   │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ ├─┬ browserify-sign@4.2.0
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ elliptic@6.5.3
│   │ │ │ │ ├─┬ hash.js@1.1.7
│   │ │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.4 
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ parse-asn1@5.1.5
│   │ │ │ │ └─┬ asn1.js@4.10.1
│   │ │ │ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@3.6.0
│   │ │ │   └── inherits@2.0.4  deduped
│   │ │ ├─┬ create-hash@1.2.0
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ cipher-base@1.0.4
│   │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ md5.js@1.3.5
│   │ │ │ │ ├─┬ hash-base@3.1.0
│   │ │ │ │ │ ├── inherits@2.0.4 
│   │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@3.6.0
│   │ │ │ │ │   └── inherits@2.0.4  deduped
│   │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ ├─┬ ripemd160@2.0.2
│   │ │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ │ └─┬ sha.js@2.4.11
│   │ │ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ ├─┬ create-hmac@1.1.7
│   │ │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ ├─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │ │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ ├─┬ stream-browserify@2.0.2
│   │ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ ├─┬ stream-http@2.8.3
│   │ │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │ └─┬ util@0.11.1
│   │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   ├─┬ terser-webpack-plugin@1.4.4
│   │ └─┬ cacache@12.0.4
│   │   └─┬ mississippi@3.0.0
│   │     ├─┬ duplexify@3.7.1
│   │     │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │     │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     ├─┬ flush-write-stream@1.1.1
│   │     │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │     │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     ├─┬ from2@2.3.0
│   │     │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │     │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     ├─┬ parallel-transform@1.2.0
│   │     │ ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     │ └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │     │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     ├─┬ pumpify@1.5.1
│   │     │ └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   │     └─┬ through2@2.0.5
│   │       └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│   │         └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   └─┬ watchpack@1.7.4
│     └─┬ watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.0
│       └─┬ chokidar@2.1.8
│         ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│         └─┬ readdirp@2.2.1
│           └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│             └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY @nestjs/platform-express@7.3.2
│ ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY body-parser@1.19.0
│ │ └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY http-errors@1.7.2
│ │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│ └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY multer@1.4.2
│   ├─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY busboy@0.2.14
│   │ └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY readable-stream@1.1.14
│   │   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│   └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY concat-stream@1.6.2
│     ├── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
│     └─┬ UNMET DEPENDENCY readable-stream@2.3.7
│       └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
├─┬ rimraf@3.0.2
│ └─┬ glob@7.1.6
│   └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
├─┬ supertest@4.0.2
│ └─┬ superagent@3.8.3
│   └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
│     └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 
└─┬ ts-loader@6.2.2
  └─┬ enhanced-resolve@4.3.0
    └─┬ memory-fs@0.5.0
      └─┬ readable-stream@2.3.7
        └── UNMET DEPENDENCY inherits@2.0.3 

npm ERR! missing: @nestjs/platform-express@7.3.2, required by only-dev-deps@0.0.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by crypto-browserify@3.12.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by browserify-aes@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by browserify-des@1.0.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by des.js@1.0.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by elliptic@6.5.3
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by hash.js@1.1.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by asn1.js@4.10.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by create-hash@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by cipher-base@1.0.4
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by md5.js@1.3.5
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by ripemd160@2.0.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by sha.js@2.4.11
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by create-hmac@1.1.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by stream-browserify@2.0.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by stream-http@2.8.3
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by util@0.11.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by duplexify@3.7.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by flush-write-stream@1.1.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by from2@2.3.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by parallel-transform@1.2.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by pumpify@1.5.1
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by chokidar@2.1.8
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: body-parser@1.19.0, required by @nestjs/platform-express@7.3.2
npm ERR! missing: multer@1.4.2, required by @nestjs/platform-express@7.3.2
npm ERR! missing: http-errors@1.7.2, required by body-parser@1.19.0
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by http-errors@1.7.2
npm ERR! missing: busboy@0.2.14, required by multer@1.4.2
npm ERR! missing: concat-stream@1.6.2, required by multer@1.4.2
npm ERR! missing: readable-stream@1.1.14, required by busboy@0.2.14
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@1.1.14
npm ERR! missing: readable-stream@2.3.7, required by concat-stream@1.6.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by concat-stream@1.6.2
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by glob@7.1.6
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
npm ERR! missing: inherits@2.0.3, required by readable-stream@2.3.7
```

If I run `npm ddp` it resolves `inherits` dependency problem, but then `Error: Cannot find module 'minimist'` starts.

The only way to solve this is installing all dependencies.

I want to install only `devDependencies` to layer it on docker and also to save time during build time on CI.

`npm -v`: 6.14.7

`node -v`: 10.21.0

I created [this](https://github.com/ndeitch/only-dev-deps) repo to reproduce this problem.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to only install dev dependencies?

Comment: I edited question, but it's mostly to layer it on docker and save time on build phase

Comment: You should be installing only prod deps to cache those and then install everything. It doesn't really make sense to only install dev dependencies

Comment: Yes, you're right there is no effect, since changing `package.json` would skip cache and this applies for both dev and non dev deps, but I was puzzled why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a [npm issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/477).

Using [pnpm](https://pnpm.js.org/) works fine.

`pnpm install --dev`

Then `npm run build` runs without module not found error